# findFragmentById returns null for fragment after migration to AndroidX

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, androidx, fragmentmanager

After migration to AndroidX, findFragmentById (findFragmentByTag also) started returning null when I tried to obtain fragment.

Fragment is added in XML like this:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/id_fragment"
        android:tag="tag_fragment"
        android:name="com.blaa.MyFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Fragment looks like this:

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
...
}
```

and Activity looks like this:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
...
}
```

dependencies:

```
...
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03"
...
```

and here is how I call it inside the code:

```
supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.id_fragment)
```

or

```
supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(R.id.tag_fragment)
```

both return null. I also tried using just fragmentManager, with null result 
 and it will not work anyway because it returns simple fragment, not androidx one.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Have you updated your gradle.properties?

Comment: Completing @Ricardo's comment, have you added 
`android.useAndroidX=true` and 
`android.enableJetifier=true` to your `gradle.properties`?

Comment: @Wang have you read the question? the jetifier has a whole other purpose.

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes, of course, what is making you doubtful in my comment? I don't think that it's unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Wang I think that both comments miss the actual question, because the `name` attribute is obviously referencing an instance of `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`... and `androidx` is nothing else, but a repackaged support library. the name-space is the only difference there, while the jetifier transforms the name-space of third-party libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index access, alike `fm.getFragments().get(0)` or `fm.getFragments().get(1)`, might work.

and if it doesn't ...it might not be able to find it, because it hadn't been added yet (a timing issue).

`fm.getFragments()` is at least useful, to see what is even available, at the current point of time.

Comment: What I forgot to mention that this fragment is nested inside another fragment which is inside activity. "getFragments" returned only this one top-level fragment, and it's childFragmentManager finally revealed my fragments. Looks like supportFragmentManager now shows only direct childs. Your answer lead me to the solution, so thanks :)